# T-SQL- Difficult logical queries

Tags: sql, .net

I am working on an interesting project and I must admit SQL is not my strong point. My problem, in a nutshell, is this:

Assume a table that holds pairs of users sharing a particular relation.
(e.g. (John, Mary, Friends), (Mary, Alice, Friends))
Is there a way to write a query which would yield John's friend of a friend, in this case, Alice, but without also returning Mary as a result? And could such a query be extended to an arbitrary n length that would always yield a set of pairs as a result excluding the inbetween users?

Similarly:
A query which would yield - How many friends does John have in common with Alice? (In this case,1)

Or - How many friends belong in the same type of relationship, provided the relationship starts and ends with the same person : (e.g. John, Mary,Alice,John - Friendship).

I am sorry if the post sounds silly - I know I've never had to worry about such things on a SQL level before, where SQL was mostly used for inserting, updating and retrieving data in the form of reports.
Dynamic query creation is not an issue - I am moreso interested in the architectural logic of the query.
This is different, and I wonder if there is a way to do in SQL or if I should instead try and do it in the business level of my code (using .NET for example)

Many thanks.

Comment: Lookup hierarchical queries.  Depending on RDBMS and version the syntax and abilities vary.  Use of unions and common table expressions can solve this issue in some cases, in other cases, you don't have the necessary features in the RDBMS to do it easily.

Comment: I've got to admit I'm not exactly sure what you're asking... there's a lot of questions hidden in there. Should you do BL in the DB? No. Should you use it to get the friends of X or find the friends in common between these people? Yes. How would you write these queries? That depends on your schema and database system!

Comment: I am sorry _ I understand it can be confusing. think of it in plain English (it helps me ! ). I am George and Alice is my friend. Mary is Alice's friend, but not my friend. Kim is Mary's friends, and noone else's friend. If I wanted to find someone who is a friend, of my friend, of my friend (in this case, Kim), my first thought was dynamic queries and multiple joins. However - That doesn't stop the join from joining previous pairs as well as forward ones. How could I reach a result of : George, Kim and nothing else?

Comment: Could you provide some test data (with the multiple levels of relationships) along with an expected answer, as well as two or three that SHOULDN'T me a match in the same query.

Comment: What database engine and version is this?  Oracle (10g,11g?), MySQL, SQL Server (2000? 2005,2008(R2), 2012, 2014?) Postgresql? Db2?  Perhaps you could post structure and sample data to a http://sqlfiddle.com/ that could be used as an stepping point into a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this table structure:

```
    TABLE [dbo].[Pers](
    [PersID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Pers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

For the persons, and:

```
TABLE [dbo].[Rels](
    [RelID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RelFrom] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RelTo] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Rels] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

for the relations between the persons (friends).

And with this data:

```
PersID  Name
1   John
2   Mary
3   Alice

RelID   RelFrom RelTo
1   1   2
2   2   3
```

You could use this query:

```
select p.Name,frofr.Name
from Pers as p
    inner join Rels as f1 on f1.RelFrom=p.PersID
    inner join Rels as f2 on f2.RelFrom=f1.Relto
    inner join Pers as frofr on frofr.PersID=f2.RelTo
```

With this result:

```
Name    Name
John    Alice
```

You can create as many relations as you want, but for each level you should extend the query.
You could create views for each 'friend-level'.
I would not use this for 100K+ records, for that sort of cases you may be better of with constructing tree-like structures.

Comment: Brilliant.This is definitely a step to the right direction for table design for me. I'll mark your answer as correct and be sure to bother you with more questions now that i've found you. Thank you ! However - a relation can also be multi-directional. Meaning, using your table, John is a friend to Mary. But Mary is also a friend to John. My initial thought was using 'WHERE ... Not equals to... ' to stop backtracking.

Comment: I used relfrom and relto only as an example. You could also see it as left/right or r1/r2. It just to state that there is a relation between the two persons. 
With this setup, you're super flexible because your structure is very fundamental. You could add a relation type column to indicate the type of relation: friend, parent, boss, etc...

And with this setup, if mary is no friend of alice any more, john is automatically no friend of friend from alice.

I suppose you're not building a LinkedIn clone :)